# Error en registrar usuario nuevo - PHP

Tags: php

Al enviar los datos, siempre me muestra el siguiente mensaje de error, personalizado:

> Ha ocurrido un error internamente, por favor, vuelva intertar enviar su solicitud más tarde

No tengo más detalles que adjuntar, no me muestra ningún otro error.

```
<?php
//session_start();
include "app/php/require.ini.php";

if (isset($_POST['formsubmitted'])) {
    $msg = array();

    if (empty($_POST['username'])) {
        $msg[] = 'Por favor, ingrese un nombre de usuario';
    } else {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
    }

    if (empty($_POST['email'])) {
        $msg[] = 'Por favor, ingrese su correo electrónico';
    } else {
        if (preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)+$/", $_POST['email'])) {
            $email = $_POST['email'];
        } else {
            $msg[] = 'Tu dirección de correo electrónico no es válida';
        }
    }

    if (strlen($_POST['password']) <6){
        $msg[] = 'Su contraseña debe tener al menos 6 caracteres';
    }
    if ($_POST['password'] !== $_POST['password_again']){
        $msg[] = 'Su contraseña no coincide';
    } else {
        $password = $_POST['password'];
    }

    if (empty($_POST['firstname'])) {
        $msg[] = 'Por favor, ingrese su nombre';
    } else {
        $first_name = $_POST['firstname'];
    }

    if (empty($msg)) {
        $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=? OR username=?");
        $stmt->bind_param("ss",$email,$username);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();

        if ($stmt->num_rows>0) {
            echo "¡El usuario con este correo electrónico ya existe!";
        } else {

            $hash_password = password_hash($password, CRYPT_BLOWFISH);
            $key = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32));
            //$key_two = bin2hex(random_bytes(32)); // Disponible apartir de PHP V.7
            //$active_default = 0;
            $stmtA = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, email, password, first_name, email_code) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
            $stmtA->bind_param("sssss", $username,$email,$hash_password,$first_name,$key);

            if($stmtA->execute()){
                echo 'El enlace de confirmación ha sido enviado por correo electrónico. ¡Por favor, haga clic en el enlace del mensaje para activar su cuenta!';

                $to = $email;
                $subject = "Por favor, verifique su cuenta.";
                $message_body = 'Hola '.$first_name.',
                ¡Gracias por registrarte!

                Estas aún solo paso de ser parte de nuestra comunidad.

                Por favor, haga clic en este enlace para activar su cuenta:

                http://localhost/login-system/verify.php?email='.urlencode($email).'&key='.$key.'';
                mail($to, $subject, $message_body, 'From: prueba@example.com');
                header("location: index.php");
                exit;
            } else {
                echo "Ha ocurrido un error internamente, por favor, vuelva intertar enviar su solicitud más tarde";
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<form action="register.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Usuario" value="<?php echo isset($username) ? $username: ""; ?>" >
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" value="<?php echo isset($email) ? $email: ""; ?>" >
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    <input type="password" id="password_again" name="password_again" placeholder="Password again">
    <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="Nombre" value="<?php echo isset($first_name) ? $first_name: ""; ?>" >
    <input type="submit" name="formsubmitted" value="Register" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

## Actualización

El mensaje de error personalizado ya no se muestra realizando los siguientes cambios, el reemplazo de: `if (empty($error)) {}` por `if (empty($msg)) {}`

Pero ahora, al enviar los datos del formulario en blanco, es decir, sin llenar los campos `input`, no me muestra ningún mensaje de error.

Comment: En tu `else` agrégale un `print_r($stmtA-errorInfo());` para ver en detalle el error

Comment: @Dibort Hola, su código me ejecuta este error `Fatal error: Call to undefined function errorInfo()`

Comment: Perdón, es `$con->errorInfo();` en vez de `$stmtA->errorInfo();`

Comment: @Dibort Esa características es de uso [PDO](http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.errorinfo.php), Lo he realizado de una menera distinta print_r($stmtA); y me muestra lo siguiente `mysqli_stmt Object ( [affected_rows] => -1 [insert_id] => 0 [num_rows] => 0 [param_count] => 5 [field_count] => 0 [errno] => 1048 [error] => Column 'username' cannot be null [error_list] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [errno] => 1048 [sqlstate] => 23000 [error] => Column 'username' cannot be null ) ) [sqlstate] => 23000 [id] => 3 )`

Comment: @OscarGarcia Hola, no me muestra nada referencial, solo registra errores sobre esto `print_r($stmtA-errorInfo());` de ahí ningún error más.

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar mejor **pero ahora, al enviar los datos del formulario en blanco, no me muestra ningún mensaje de error**? Además, si la respuesta que te ofrecieron te solucionó el problema deberías marcarla como correcta y plantear la nueva duda en una nueva pregunta con los cambios realizados.

Comment: @OscarGarcia Una pregunta nueva, pero sigo sin poder registrar un usuario nuevo, no me registra el usuario a pesar de llenar los datos.

Comment: @Karla , los mensajes de error que acumulas en `$msg` ¿dónde se supone que deben aparecer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que los mensajes de error que se han producido durante el envío se muestren una vez enviado el formulario deberías agregar lo siguiente en alguna parte de tu HTML:

```
<?php
/* Si existe $msg y contiene mensajes de error los mostramos */
if (isset($msg) && count($msg) > 0) {
    /* Mostramos un encabezado para todos los mensaje de error */
?><p>Se han encontrado los siguientes errores:
  <ul>
<?php
    /* Los listamos uno a uno como elementos de una lista <li>
        sin numeración <ul> */
    foreach ($msg as $mensaje) {
?>    <li><?= htmlspecialchars($mensaje) ?></li>
<?php
    }
?>  </ul>
</p>
<?php
}
?>
```

Otra forma alternativa de implementarlo es:

```
<?php if (isset($msg) && count($msg) > 0): ?>
<p>Se han encontrado los siguientes errores:
  <ul>
<?php foreach ($msg as $mensaje): ?>
    <li><?= htmlspecialchars($mensaje) ?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
  </ul>
</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Se me cae el rostro de la vergüenza, como pude olvidar ese detalle ;(

Comment: No te preocupes @Karla, es normal que ocurra. Muchos errores no somos capaces de verlos nosotros mismos hasta que una segunda persona lo mira.

Comment: Gracias, puedes mirar por favor el siguiente código https://ideone.com/mZrjaq no quiero tener otra vergüenza :( en mis descuidos, siempre me muestra este mensaje `Redirrecionar a otro sitio` y no me activa la cuenta del usuario, por favor puedes mirarlo

Comment: En cuanto a los datos bien relleno, dijiste que no se introducían en la base de datos, ¿eso lo tienes ya solucionado? Y por último un consejo: no uses asignaciones indirectas como  `$email = $_POST['email']` y luego `$to = $email;` y `mail($to, ..);`. Son propensas a errores cuando cambias algo. Es mejor usar asignación directa: `mail($_POST['email'], ..);`.

Comment: ¿Y el HTML? ¿Cómo generas `$_GET['key']` y sabes que son siempre 32 caracteres?

Comment: Si lo solucione, los datos, también estaba enlazando una base de datos antigua, huy no me esta yendo nada bien en la programación muchos descuidos tengo.

Comment: Tranquilidad y un segundo punto de vista es lo que se necesita en el 99% de las ocasiones ;) ¡suerte con el proyecto!

Comment: Sí yo los controlo de la siguiente forma `$key = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32));` en mi pregunta esta :(

Comment: Pero `bin2hex()` convierte cada byte (8 bits) en 2 caracteres (4 + 4 bits de cada dígito hexadecimal). Serían 64 caracteres en total :) mira una URL y cuenta los caracteres, verás que no coincide con lo que tenías en mente ;)

Comment: Dios mio jajaja Gracias :)